# Confirmation on splitmuxsink overrun required

Tags: gstreamer, recording, multimedia, imx6

I am recording video frames at 30 fps , resolution 1080p with h.264 encoder set at 16000kbps. The recorded frames are stored over the network to a remote hard disk drive.

When the network becomes low, I see below logs

```
0:22:23.591589000 22164 000000002ECC2180 DEBUG           splitmuxsink gstsplitmuxsink.c:2359:handle_mq_input:<queue0:sink> Buf TS +0:22:12.337900000 total GOP bytes 216631
0:22:23.591651000 22164 000000002ECC2180 DEBUG           splitmuxsink gstsplitmuxsink.c:2523:handle_q_overrun:<queue0> Queue reported overrun with 1 keyframes and 0 cmds enqueued
0:22:23.591701000 22164 000000002ECC2180 DEBUG           splitmuxsink gstsplitmuxsink.c:2551:handle_q_overrun:<queue0> Queue overflowed and needs enlarging. Growing to 54 buffers
```

What exactly is `Queue overflowed and needs enlarging`. Follow up question , could this be a possible entity to increase the virtual memory / memory consumption by the pipeline ?